# Feature request: translate words in many languages using a single question

Tags: feature-request

I have a certain situation where I want to translate a certain word or the name of an object in as many languages possible. Google translate and other dictionaries do not contain that word. And then, instead of going to the Spanish, French, German, Russian SE sites and to ask the question in many places and consuming a lot of time with such a repetitive task, I need to ask the question in one place, where the users can reply "In the language X, the name of that thing is Y". There shouldn't be an "accepted answer" as there can be hundreds of correct answers - each one for a different language.

Is there any chance the Stack Exchange can implement that?

The word I'm looking for at this moment is "Cancioc" - in Romanian - a tool used in masonry, but only in the Eastern Europe, it seems - [image1](https://www.emag.ro/cancioc-kubala-profesional-handgrip-1531/pd/D01Y0DBBM/) - [image2](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-old-used-hand-bucket-for-trowel-isolated-on-white-61690157.html) - I'm quite sure such a situation occurred for many other people before - when they simply can't manage to find the name of an object in any other language. Therefore I think that facilitating such a feature would be a really good thing for everyone.

Comment: "*There shouldn't be an "accepted answer" as there can be hundreds of correct answers - each one for a different language.*" but that's not how SE works and the question should be closed as too broad because there are too many possible valid answers.

Answer (score 4):

You have a word in one language and you want it translated to many other languages in one step?

Almost entirely over stackexchange, ling.SE, french.SE, german.SE etc, simple translation of single words is very much off-topic. It's just not an appropriate use of SE in the single pair situation, whether you ask in the target language site or in the source language site.

So it would be even worse for multiple targets at once.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not a good use of the Stack Exchange system.

Comment: Sorry but I have to believe the contrary. It would be very useful for everybody and it would reduce the time consumed to ask the same question many times for many distinct languages. Also it wouldn't require any effort to adapt the software to such a multi-answer use.

Comment: That's a tortured definition of *"useful"* or *"everybody."*